# Swift - Create charts(bar, line, pie, column) programatically

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts framework.
As per tutorials, we have to create an outlet for view then make it class as corresponding chart view.
So I created 4 outlets and successfully loaded charts.
I just want one outlet to be used for all the charts.
I am displaying charts in tableview. So can I reuse one view to all charts.
I tried by calling init() method. But, init() method is not available for all the charts.
Also, i tried giving frame also but failed.
Kindly help.

Comment: Please dont downvote directly. If there is any problem. kindly explain

Comment: Have you tried yourself? Instead of just throwing out a question why not put in some effort and try yourself and then ask about any issues you ran into. You will get a much more positive response if you have shown some effort like, being more specific about what you ask and/or including your code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This was educating.

Comment: @ManeeshAucharla - welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you look into documentation for charts a bit more, you would probably for example if you make a line chart `LineChartView()` you can have different update functions to change how it looks, for example here is one of mine:

```
func lineChartUpdate(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    //Graph data management
    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<prices.count {

        //Graph marker from extension

        if prices != [] {

            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            lineChartEntry.append(value)

            let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "Price")

            line1.setColor(.white)
            line1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
            line1.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
            line1.mode = .cubicBezier
            line1.lineWidth = 2.0
            line1.drawValuesEnabled = true
            line1.valueTextColor = UIColor.white
            line1.drawCirclesEnabled = false

            chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:self.days)
            chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
            chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            //Expanded

            chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
            chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
            chartView.xAxis.enabled = false

            chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            chartView.legend.enabled = false

            chartView.dragEnabled = false
            chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
            chartView.drawMarkers = false
            chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false

                self.chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            //Graph Data.

                let data = LineChartData()
                data.addDataSet(line1)
                self.chartView.data = data
            self.chartLoaded = true 

        }

    }

}
```

If you want one view to be able to act as a Bar chart and a line chart, it may just be easier to have a View for each type in the same place, and you can change for example a Bar chart view to any type of bar chart you want and update it to change as much as you want reusing the view, but when you need a line chart just hide that view and use the line chart instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help